# How can I apply dplyr's select(,starts_with()) on rows, not columns?

Tags: r, select

I'm now trying to figure out a way to select data having specific values in a variable, or specific letters, especially using similar algorithm that `starts_with()` does.

Say I have a data named "school" as below:

```
Name Math English
James 80   90
Tom   91   91
Shaun 99   71
Jack  92   91
```

here, `select(school, starts_with("M"))` gives me the column "Math" only.
I want to apply this on rows, such as to command 'give me the rows where name starts with "J" letter', which will in turn give me a data frame with two rows.

I tried transposing the data and succeeded at what I wanted to get, but it's not what I really want though.

How can get this to work?

Comment: You need `filter`, not `select` - `filter(school,substr(Name,1,1)=="J")`

Comment: filter(grepl("^J", Name))

Comment: or `df[grepl("^J", df$Name), ]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting rows in data.frame based on character strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067704/selecting-rows-in-data-frame-based-on-character-strings) Or [Get all the rows with rownames starting with ABC111](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20825689/get-all-the-rows-with-rownames-starting-with-abc111)

Comment: Thank you all! I thought filter was not gonna work itout but it does!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe that the combination of dplyr's filter and the substring command are the most efficient:

```
library(dplyr)
filtered_df <- school %>% dplyr::filter(substr(Name,1,1) == "J")
```

Answer (score 24):

I think  this will work:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- df %>% filter(str_detect(Name, "^J"))
```

Comment: For those with big datasets and looking at grepl @Keiku's [benchmarking of grepl and str_detect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40233929/4606130) shows str_detect is faster

Comment: @pjperez can you do data.table operation?